# Why like numbers add the incorrect total, and why minus and multiply and divide is correct

Tags: javascript

I write

```
var a= prompt("Please enter a number")
var b= prompt("Please enter a number")
```

I have typed 7&7 in the box but why the total of a+b comes out with 77? I just want the total comes out with 14, not 77. I 
can't understand why like numbers add the incorrect total and why minus and multiply and divide is correct.

Comment: See documentation on the [addition operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition), and what [prompt() returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt#Syntax)

Answer (score 2):

A string is returned from `prompt` when user clicks `OK` and `null` if `cancel` is clicked. So concatenation of two string that is "7" + "7" is "77".Use `parseInt` or [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) constructor to convert string to number before addition

```js
var a = prompt("Please enter a number");
var b = prompt("Please enter a number");
console.log(typeof a, typeof b)

let sum = parseInt(a, 10) + parseInt(b, 10);
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = Number(prompt("Enter first number"));
var b = Number(prompt("Enter second number"));
alert(a + b);
```

Note: Avoid parseInt because it only handles the leading characters and will not add floating numbers like 6.8 and 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` are strings and `string + string` is concatenating the 2 strings and not adding the values.

One quick way to convert a string into a number is adding `+` before the string ( In this case before `prompt` )

Like:

```js
var a = +prompt("Please enter a number");
var b = +prompt("Please enter a number");

var sum = a + b;

console.log(sum);
```